# User input value vs db array value not validating using JSON

Tags: php, json, wordpress, variables

**UPDATED QUESTION AFTER MUCH TESTING**

This is a strange one but hopefully someone can point out the flaw.

[image: Validation check failing even though values match]

The value shown in background box at the bottom "3333" is the value pulled from the database out of a post_meta array.

The array (custom_group) looks like:

> a:5:{s:23:"custom1";s:2:"15";s:23:"custom_value";s:1:"5";s:14:"custom3";s:1:"8";s:14:"custom4";s:11:"Free
>   Coffee";s:12:"custom_code";s:4:"3333";}

I extract it using this function:

```
public static function get_business_vars($key)
{
    global $post;

    $results = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_group', true);
    return $results[$key];
}

$code = get_business_vars('custom_code')
```

The value in the alert is the value entered by the user which is sent through the following JSON check:

```
 if ( check_ajax_referer( 'nonce_' . $data['post_id'], 'nonce', false ) == false ) {
            wp_send_json_error();
        }
        //check entry against validation
        $code = get_business_vars('custom_code');
        if ( $data['report'] !== $code) {
            wp_send_json_error();
        } else {
            wp_send_json_success();
        }
```

So, even though the POST data shows report as 3333 and the variables $code echos 3333, I only get the JSON error message.

This even returns "yes":

```
            if (get_business_vars('custom_code') == 3333) {
                echo "yes";
            } else {
                echo "no";
            }
```

and

```
if ( strval($code) !== strval(intval($code)) ) {
                echo "Your variable is not an integer";
              } else {
                  echo "yes it is";
              }
```

Prints: “yes it is”

The only way I can get the JSON to validate is by using:

```
if ( $data['report'] !== "3333") {
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try use `!=` instead of `!==` to see if it's a type error. If it is, you'll probably have to cast it to the right type

Comment: Nope, still the same :/  I have tested is_numeric on the db value and it is.

Comment: Interestingly, it passed when I changed it to if ( $data['report'] != 3333) {

Comment: is_numeric() tests if variable is number or a numeric string! so string "3333" is numeric but not integer and thus !== to 3333 integer. Use casting to avoid this

Comment: I tried         $code = (string)$code;
        $ucode = $data['report'];
        $ucode = (string)$ucode;
        if ( $ucode !== $code) { but it still shows the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the compared values to integers and then comparing them:

```
    if ( (int)$data['report'] !== (int)$code ) {
        wp_send_json_error();
    }
```

Comment: This now hangs and doesn't produce any message.

Comment: Does it produce any errors? if yes, then you first problem is solved, now it's running the else statment, please update you question with the full code you're using.

Comment: I asked you to update it so I can see if there is anything wrong with it.

Comment: Try the new code, there was a mistake in the old one

Comment: Then please share the full code you are using, update you question

Comment: Ali, does it ring any alarm bells that the $code value pulled from the db is from inside a serialised array?  Yes it echos 3333 but what "type" is that by default.  I ask this because in another file I run a multiplcation using another value from this same array and that is not working either.  On my other server where these values are in separate meta keys all of this code works fine.